# From where can I get the impedance graph/ frequency response information of a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, frequency-response

I want to know the self resonant frequency (SRF) of a tantalum or aluminum capacitor. Is this usually supposed to be there in the datasheet?

I am wondering why it is not mentioned in datasheet since it is an important piece of information to really judge the effectiveness of a capacitor (to remove the ripple current) at a given switching frequency.

Only ESR and capacitance is given. ESL information is missing completely. Same issue with multiple manufacturer datasheets.

https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/ABE0000/ABE0000C51.pdf
https://datasheet.octopart.com/TCNT476M016R0200-AVX-datasheet-66474706.pdf

Comment: ESL is usually rather small, and is *very dependent* on layout, lead length. Why should a manufacturer specify something that is so user-dependent? Specifying ESL may make sense when the internal structure of a capacitor contains inductance that is a significant portion of a capacitor's total series inductance in its final position.

Comment: FYI, the element these capacitors are named after is [tantalum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum). There is no '/' in the name because it isn't a combination of two materials, it's an actual chemical element.

Comment: Not sure for aluminum/tantalum but for ceramic there is usually a way to find most of this information (ESR and impedance vs freq, and also SRF) on the manufacturers website. It is NOT in the datasheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most recognized suppliers of capacitors (including AVX and Panasonic) do provide extensive data on their websites regarding the important information that isn't included in their data sheets. So, go to your favourite recognized supplier (such as this one from Kemet) and look at the data under the [product part number](https://www.kemet.com/en/us/capacitors/tantalum/product/T491B106M016AT.html): -

[image]

And scroll down to you find the graph you want: -

[image]

Most decent suppliers will provide this information. Here's the detail more precisely linked to ESL: -

[image]

I don't buy components from anyone not supplying this information (if it's needed in my design). Of course a data sheet is the preferred method to get this information because it will have a revision number and date but, you can easily make your own visual record of the data as I have done in the screen shots above.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, I have misaligned AVX and Panasonic. I shall make amends....